# PCB not taking in voltage reading

Tags: microcontroller, pcb

I made a PCB with an ESP32 microcontroller. I am trying to use a single terminal to detect the current from a generator as well as the voltage. I am using an ACS712 current sensor to detect the current. The problem is that I when I put in the power supply leads, it goes to constant current mode and when I take off the current sensor chip, I can then read voltage. I know something's probably wrong with the wiring but I am still new to PCB design. Is there anything glaring about my schematic that needs to be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly like it should, you just expect it to work differently, and it is unclear how you expect it to work instead.

The ACS712 has an internal current shunt of 0.0012 ohms, so it effectively is a short circuit. Even 10 amp current would only cause a voltage of 12 millivolts. Or the other way around, 12 millivolts of voltage would require 10A of current.

Comment: If there is a 5 volt 1 amp input going into the voltage sensor terminal, why would the esp32 not be able to read in the 5 volts while at the same time getting the correct voltage output from the acs chip.

Comment: There can't be 5V and 1A, because 5V over 0.0012 ohms would require 4167 amps, so 1 amp can't produce 5V. Ohm's law.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that. From my understanding, if there is a 1A current going into the acs712 chip, the hall effect sensor will output an equivalent voltage into my esp32 microcontroller which I will then take in those voltage values and recalculate to the equivalent current reading through the firmware.

Comment: @LyndonLi Yes, if there is 1A through ACS712, there will be 0.0012V over ACS712 terminals. And it has sensitivity of 185mV per 1A so you would read 0.185V. Assuming you have the 5A version of ACS712. Now it might be better to explain what currents or voltages you expect, where and why, and how are you connecting anything to this circuit for measuring, maybe the mistake is not on this board but in the connections. Try to explain it in a way that someone else could do the same connections, e.g draw how lab power supply was attached and with what settings.

Answer (score 0):

I see one major problem.

The ACS712 current sensing pins are connected to short pin2 of the voltage sensor generator connector to ground.

The ACS712 pins IP+and IP- should be connected in series with with pin2 of that connector, if that is where you want to measure the current. Connecting a bench supply will either place the supply into constant current mode, or destroy the ACS712.

5V on pin 2 of the voltage sensor generator connector will produce at most 430 microamps of current. I do not understand where you expect 1 amp of current to come from.

Comment: The two voltage sensor generator pins will come from an external wind powered generator. When I was testing this setup out beforehand, I had used an acs712 prepackaged board and put the generator leads into the terminals of the acs board. Ideally, I would want a single terminal block to connect the generator to both the acs chip and the voltage divider for voltage sensing. Would I have to have the generator terminals going into the acs chip be completely separate from the terminals going into the voltage divider circuit?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the system, diagrams connecting the genertor to a load and what exactly you are trying to acheive. I cannot guess what you are trying to do.